# Can I see what hillshade illumination settings were used to create a particular hillshade geotiff?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, hillshade

Are the settings used to create a hillshade geotiff captured in the geotiff file somewhere? I am trying to expand the coverage of an existing hillshade and want to make sure I am using the same Illumination settings (Azimuth, Vertical Angle) as the existing portion.
Any idea where I could look up that info?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I believe it would be possible to store the parameters into some suitable TIFF metadata tags http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml. I am rather sure that in most cases you won't find anything.

Comment: PolyGeo, I am using QGIS, but I am not sure what was used to generate the original GeoTiff.